# Lax monoids where only the unit triangle is lax

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, semigroups-and-monoids

I was rereading the paper [Directoids: algebraic models of up-directed sets](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01190253) by Ježek and Quackenbush, this time with category theory in mind. When I tried to describe what the results in that paper mean from a categorial perspective, I arrived at the following simple construction.

Let $P$ be a poset with $0$, not necessarily directed. Write $\nabla$ for the relation $P\times P\to P$, where $(a_1,a_2)\nabla b$ if and only if $a_1,a_2\leq b$. Then $(P,\nabla)$ is a semigroup in the monoidal category $(\mathbf{Rel},\times,1)$. However, it is not a monoid: the arrow $0:1\to P$ does not satisfy the triangle axiom strictly, for $a\in P$ we only have $a\in\nabla(0,a)$.

> **Question:** What is the approriate categorial setting to describe such "monoids with lax unit"?

Comment: Are you looking for more than just "a lax monoid object in a 2-category whose associativity is strict"?

Comment: @MikeSchulman I do not know what I am looking for. That is the problem.

Comment: @MikeSchulman That is the setting I am working in now.
I am even assuming that the Hom-sets are posets; there are
other examples besides the one in question (try
$(\mathbf{Rel},\sqcup,\emptyset)$, it is fun).
The problem is that everything works
*too nice*, so it seems to me that I am working on a particular case
of some theory that is known for decades.

Comment: How much of your theory depends on the associativity being strict?  The theory of ordinary lax monoids is of course well-known.

Comment: @MikeSchulman I am not sure yet. The plan is to write things down in the strict setting and then to look for generalizations. I would be grateful if you could drop me a reference or two concerning the theory of "ordinary lax monoids".

Comment: One possible reference is http://maths.mq.edu.au/~street/Multicats.pdf.  (Also, note that there is no "c" in my name.)

Comment: @MikeShulman Sorry for that, and thanks. It seems that "Gray categories" is the keyword I need.

Answer (score 1):

Saavedra's (beautiful!) theory of units might help: instead of the triangle for the unit object $0$, you only demand that maps $1 \times P \stackrel{0 \times 1}{\to} P \times P \stackrel{\nabla}{\to} P$ and $P \times 1 \stackrel{1 \times 0}{\to} P \times P \stackrel{\nabla}{\to} P$ are monomorphisms. A semimonoid with this property is called a Saavedra monoid. See e.g. section 4 of this [nice paper by Kock](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0507349).

Comment: Thanks, the paper is really interesting. Alas, the maps are not monic in this case :-(.